# Кэширование данных в Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Не могу понять, после того как выполняется первый запрос к данным из таблицы в бд, последующие запросы к данным этой же таблицы идут на много быстрее. В Entity framework есть какой-то внутренний механизм кэширования ? 
P.S. Контексты каждый раз создаются заново.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь дело далеко не только в кэшировании. При первом запросе выполняется большой объем подготовительных действий, связанных с подготовкой моделей в Entity Framework. Впрочем, эти действия выполняются лишь один раз для домена приложений. Это загрузка метаданных, генерация внутренних представлений, трансляция запросов. Используется также и кэширование, причем как для данных, так и для запросов. Первый запрос из-за этого называют холодным, а последующие, выполняющиеся граздо быстрее - горячими